# Centering text in div using 'vertical-align' not working

Tags: html, css

the title pretty much sums it up. I have the following code:

```
<div class="container">
   <p>Hello world</p>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.container{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;    
    background-color: lightblue;
    vertical-align: middle; /* Why you no work!?!? */
}
```

But the text is not vertically aligning in the div. I'm clearly missing something here or don't understand a certain concept. Anybody tell me what's happening?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Vertically Align text in a Div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939914/vertically-align-text-in-a-div)

Comment: It is working, you need to set the line height to see a differance

Comment: Do you seriously get some people that as soon as a question is asked goes and checks if someone else already has, and then if so, goes and comments AND posts a link to it and mark the question 'already asked'. LOL WTF

Answer (score 2):

if you have single line text add this to your css.

.container > p{
line-height:50px;
}

Answer (score 2):

To use `vertical-align: middle`, you need to use `display: inline-block`.

Your code will change to this:

```
.container{
    display: inline-block; /* This is the line you need to introduce */
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;    
    background-color: lightblue;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

You can take a look at the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aniketpant/XpsQ7/).

### Update

Using `display: table` for `.container` and `display: table-cell` for `.container p` makes it work.

[Updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aniketpant/XpsQ7/1/)

```
.container{
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: lightblue;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.container p {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: @Salt That is because `<p>` is not going to move itself due to change in the height. Let me see if this can be done some other way.

Answer (score 1):

Vertical alignment in CSS is not as straightforward as horizontal alignment.

Depending on your case and the content you need to apply one technique or another.

You can check this link for different techniques:

http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/vertical-centering/

In short, vertical-align: center; is not going to work in your case

Answer (score 1):

Add to your container the display property as follows:

```
.container{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;    
    background-color: lightblue;
    display:inline-block; 
    vertical-align: middle; 
}
```